# React click specific element in setInterval loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to click my element in setInterval loop, so it would be clicked every 10 second, but there's always error **click is not a function** or **cannot read click null**

I've tired with useRef and also did nothing.

here is my code:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    setInterval(function () {
      const handleChangeState = () => {
        console.log("Now");
        document.getElementById("dice").click();
      };
      handleChangeState();
    }, 10 * 1000);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <Dice id="dice" rollingTime="3000" triggers={["click", "P"]} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Won't question why you want to do that, but Dice is a React Component, not a DOM element. So we need to see what is your Dice Component

Answer (score 1):

It is often considered anti-pattern in React to query the DOM. You should instead use a React ref to gain access to the underlying DOMNode.

There are a couple ways to use a React ref to invoke a dice roll of the child component. FYI, `rollingTime` should probably be number type instead of a string if using in any `setTimeout` calls.

1. Forward the React ref and attach to the `button` element and invoke the `click` handler.

   Example:

   ```
   const Dice = forwardRef(({ id, rollingTime }, ref) => {
     const timerRef = useRef();

     const [value, setValue] = useState();
     const [isRolling, setIsRolling] = useState();

     useEffect(() => {
       return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
     }, []);

     const roll = () => {
       if (!isRolling) {
         setIsRolling(true);
         clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
         timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
           setValue(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
           setIsRolling(false);
         }, rollingTime);
       }
     };

     return (
       <>
         <h1>Dice</h1>
         <h2>Roll Value: {isRolling ? "Rolling..." : value}</h2>
         <button ref={ref} id={id} type="button" onClick={roll}>
           Roll the dice
         </button>
       </>
     );
   });
   ```

   ...

   ```
   export default function App() {
     const diceRef = useRef();

     useEffect(() => {
       const handleChangeState = () => {
         console.log("Clicking Dice");
         diceRef.current?.click();
       };

       setInterval(() => {
         handleChangeState();
       }, 10 * 1000);
     }, []);

     return (
       <div className="App">
         <Dice
           ref={diceRef}
           id="dice"
           rollingTime={3000}
           triggers={["click", "P"]}
         />
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```
2. Forward the React ref and invoke the button's callback function directly via the `useImperativeHandle` hook.

   Example:

   ```
   const Dice = forwardRef(({ id, rollingTime }, ref) => {
     const timerRef = useRef();

     const [value, setValue] = useState();
     const [isRolling, setIsRolling] = useState();

     useEffect(() => {
       return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
     }, []);

     const roll = () => {
       if (!isRolling) {
         setIsRolling(true);
         clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
         timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
           setValue(Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1);
           setIsRolling(false);
         }, rollingTime);
       }
     };

     useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
       roll
     }));

     return (
       <>
         <h1>Dice 2</h1>
         <h2>Roll Value: {isRolling ? "Rolling..." : value}</h2>
         <button id={id} type="button" onClick={roll}>
           Roll the dice
         </button>
       </>
     );
   });
   ```

   ...

   ```
   export default function App() {
     const diceRef = useRef();

     useEffect(() => {
       const handleRollDice = () => {
         console.log("Roll dice");
         diceRef.current.roll();
       };

       setInterval(() => {
         handleRollDice();
       }, 10 * 1000);
     }, []);

     return (
       <div className="App">
         <Dice
           ref={diceRef}
           id="dice"
           rollingTime={3000}
           triggers={["click", "P"]}
         />
       </div>
     );
   }
   ```

[image: Edit react-click-specific-element-in-setinterval-loop]

### Using `react-dice-roll`

If you examine the `react-dice-roll` source code you'll see that the `Dice` component forwards a React ref and uses the `useImperativeHandle` hook to expose out a `rollDice` function.

[Dice Source](https://github.com/avaneeshtripathi/react-dice-roll/blob/master/src/index.tsx#L34-L128)

> ```
> const Dice = forwardRef((props: TProps, ref: React.MutableRefObject<TDiceRef>) => {
>     ...
>
>     const handleDiceRoll = (value?: TValue) => {
>         let diceAudio: HTMLAudioElement;
>         if (sound) {
>             diceAudio = new Audio(sound);
>             diceAudio.play();
>         }
>         setRolling(true);
>         setTimeout(() => {
>             let rollValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1) as TValue;
>
>             if (value) rollValue = value;
>             if (cheatValue) rollValue = cheatValue;
>             
>             setRolling(false);
>             setValue(rollValue);
>             
>             if (diceAudio) diceAudio.pause();
>             if (!onRoll) return;
>             onRoll(rollValue);
>         }, rollingTime);
>     };
>
>     useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({ rollDice: handleDiceRoll }));
>
>     ...
>
>     return (
>       ...
>     )
> });
> ```

Your code then just needs to create a React ref and pass it to the `Dice` component, and instantiate the interval in a mounting `useEffect` hook.

Example:

```
function App() {
  const diceRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const rollDice = () => {
      console.log("Rolling Dice");
      diceRef.current.rollDice(); // <-- call rollDice function
    };

    // instantiate interval
    setInterval(() => {
      rollDice();
    }, 10 * 1000);

    // immediately invoke so we don't wait 10 seconds for first roll
    rollDice();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Dice
        ref={diceRef}
        id="dice"
        rollingTime={3000}
        triggers={["click", "P"]}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit react-click-specific-element-in-setinterval-loop (forked)]

Comment: I'm using library 'react-dice-roll'. Before i asked a question i've tried with useRef and i'm getting **diceRef.current.click is not a function** error

Comment: @Publius This is because the real `Dice` component exposes out a `rollDice` function. It's viewable in the source code. I've updated my answer, please do check it out.